# not of type Boolean error message when testing Stripe in Test Mode

Tags: stripe, testing

I am getting the following error message when testing Stripe recurring membership dues in test mode:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred.
>
> - One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Boolean

any help with how to fix this would be greatly appreciated,
best regards,
David

Comment: what version please?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the help. The versions are Stripe 5.3.2 Extension, CiviCRM 5.13.1, wordpress 5.2

Comment: Ok, with 5.3.2 there are still some issues running in test mode.  These will all be resolved in the next (5.4) release but for now you can put the test keys into the live processor for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has a ticket in Gitlab so you can follow updates there: 
https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues/53